# UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to load dll in my eclipse project

Tags: java, exception, dllimport, loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have 'xxx.dll' file along with a couple of other dlls at the location -

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\xyz\Librerias'
```

trying to load this dll file in my project using

```
System.loadLibrary("xxx");
```

added this path to 'Native library location' in JRE System Library in Configure Build Path but still the line trying to load this dll is throwing 'UnsatisfiedLinkError'.

I even tried but still same error remains.

```
System.load("C:/Program Files (x86)/abc/xyz/Librerias/xxx.dll");
```

I do have latest version of 32-bit JRE and JDK added in my system path and I am using a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Ah! Looks like the file cannot be loaded, try changing the path to something like  `System.load("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\abc\\xyz\\Librerias\\xxx.dll");`

Comment: No. I tried that, still the same issue.

Comment: Please, can you verify if the library `xxx.dll` exists at the given path? May be there is some permission issue, because it is in the `C:\Program Files` path? Try copying the said library to some other path, provide an absolute path and re-try. Also, note that if the library is already loaded by your application and the application tries to load it again, the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` will be thrown by the `JVM`.

Comment: Yes. Library exists. It is the first dll that is tried to be loaded to the application so no chance for the second case. I tried copying them outside and referring absolute path but no luck. The answer I provide solved the issue any thoughts on why such a change worked?

Answer (score 0):

The system was not able to navigate to that directory because of those non-existent paths. In order to solve that I just did opposite, added location of native library in front of PATH and it worked like a charm.

[this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in.html) helped.